# Reg-Ex to partially extract an array stored in a file

Tags: php, regex, arrays

If I have an array properly structured stored in a file like this:

**array.php**

```
<?php  

return array(

  0=>"a",
  "x"=>$timestamp,
  "y"=>array("nested"=>array(1,2,3)),  
  "z"=>function() use (&$VAR) { return $VAR; },

);  

?>
```

**what kind of RegEx should I use to get an array like this:**

```
$array=file_get_contents("array.php"); // a string ready to be processed
```

> /* some kind of magic regex */

```
$array[0]=>'"a"';
$array["x"]=>'$timestamp';
$array["y"]=>'array("nested"=>array(1,2,3))';  
$array["z"]='function() use (&$VAR) { return $VAR; }';
```

**?**

---

update :: i need $array contains values like these, so i can call eval() selectively where and when i need it, like this

```
$timestamp="2010-01-01 00:00:00";
$dinamicValue=eval(" return ".$array["x"]."; "); // now is "2010-01-01 00:00:00"

$timestamp="2012-01-01 00:00:00";
$dinamicValue=eval(" return ".$array["x"]."; "); // now is "2012-01-01 00:00:00"
```

it will be used for some kind of template system, here is a template demo [codepad.org/xt56tXnf](http://codepad.org/xt56tXnf) where all vars like $DINAMIC_VALUE_* should be defined dinamically.

Comment: `i do not expect comments like 'why you do that?'` No but seriously...Why would you do that!? Also I imagine the only solution would be to loop by lines and use `regex` for this.

Comment: i know this may seems "fancy", but sometimes when developing apps with specific custom behaviour this sort of things are required P:

Comment: yep! i think some regex can help here...

Comment: Can you edit your question please to elaborate why you need this to be a Regex solution *at any cost*? It sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) tbh. Basically, what is your scenario? What are you trying to achieve? Focus on the What. Not the How.

Comment: @Gordon ok, i will add it P:

Comment: thanks for updating. It still doesn't make much sense to me though. The simple fact that it's using eval and you apparently have to go through hoops to make this work should tell you that it's not a good solution. Maybe you should rethink your approach there.

Comment: @Gordon no, thanks to you for your attentions!!, ok i will research P:

Answer (score 1):

You can acomplish the same thing by doing

```
$timestamp="2013-04-24 12:44:04";  
$userid=4;

$array=include('array.php');
```

To get a partial you could implement the array.php to contain multiple conditional return;

Comment: good try but not what i want! in this case, variable assignment SHOULD BE AFTER call to include() P:

Comment: so you can eval multiple times with different parameter values?

Comment: Would you be open to an alternate file format to expression than a php array ... say an xml doc?

Comment: i think it can't help, because some times array.php will contain elements with closures(), and maybe xml doc is too complex to solve this little requirement :3

Comment: closures... this sounds familiar... would this happen to be for a templateing system?

Comment: what kind of magician is this??, yep!!, the file array.php is in fact a template, i should clarify this kind of templates need get values of any type (int,string,array) and in some ocassiones do specific processing with closures.

Comment: Check out this toy project of mine .... https://github.com/cgray/templar you might be able to draw some inspiration this. :)

Comment: "Templar"... sounds like a Starcraft Protoss Official App xD, yay!! hey, thanks!! let me check it :3

Comment: I dodged the whole file_get_contents/eval problem by making a stream wrapper that wraps the included content in an anonymous function. So you end up with a template function that you pass your template variables into.

Comment: ok!, i updated my question, can check my sample template code and tell me if Templar* can help me here??

Comment: Not as currently implemented but I think some of the techniques may be applicable.

Comment: is the value of the method key in each section basically the php for the body of a class method?

Comment: in fact, string value on key "method" is a partial path to an php file who contains a function to be executed passing only "params" as function arguments, then returns an array like this array("status"=>(bool),"msg"=>(string),"data"=>(array)) indicating execution status.